# Immutable stream batching

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

Is there an immutable alternative to the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58471183/akka-stream-batching) question, which batches up data in a stream:

```
val records =
  Source(List(
    Record(1, "a"),
    Record(1, "k"),
    Record(1, "k"),
    Record(1, "a"),
    Record(2, "r"),
    Record(2, "o"),
    Record(2, "c"),
    Record(2, "k"),
    Record(2, "s"),
    Record(3, "!")
  ))
  .concat(Source.single(Record(0, "notused"))) // needed to print the last element

records
  .statefulMapConcat { () =>
    var currentTime = 0
    var payloads: Seq[String] = Nil

    record =>
      if (record.time == currentTime) {
        payloads = payloads :+ record.payload
        Nil
      } else {
        val previousState = (currentTime, payloads)
        currentTime = record.time
        payloads = Seq(record.payload)
        List(previousState)
      }
  }
  .runForeach(println)
```

Produces

```
(0,List())
(1,List(a, k, k, a))
(2,List(r, o, c, k, s))
(3,List(!))
```

Comment: Probably using fold

Comment: @cchantep right, presumably also substreams, since fold only emits at the end of the stream

Answer (score 0):

you're on a good way, immutability and stateless is a important aspect in programming concurrent distributed software.
I share this [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ZLYZefIRQ52LgRc7hKVjTw) with your sample code while using groupBy from [akka](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-cookbook.html#implementing-reduce-by-key).
Let me know, if it will help you.
The output is like

```
(3,List(!))
(1,List(a, k, k, a))
(2,List(r, o, c, k, s))
```